# Error during Twitter Connect in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, twitter

Facing this error during the connection of Twitter in Wordpress  login

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in /home/mjoneja/public_html/wp-includes/capabilities.php on line 497

How to overcome this kind of issue ?

Comment: Specify the version of wordpress and the plugins used. Also, the error message is not the actual error, but just a combination of another error and faulty error handling (Trying to use an Exception as a string)

Comment: WP-Version 3.3.2 and Twit Connect Version 2.59

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Twit Connect plugin page](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/twitconnect/):

```
Compatible up to: 3.2.1
Last Updated: 2011-10-4
```

Your Wordpress version is too new for the Plugin. Also, the plugin doesn't seem to be in development anymore as the last update is almost a year old... you should choose a different twitter plugin which works with your wordpress version and is actively maintained. Sadly I can't recomment one because I don't use wordpress...

Comment: Find nowhere which supports WP-Version 3.3.2 ? any help ?

Comment: you can search the [plugins page](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/) to see if you find another plugin, or look at some wordpress pages with a twitter integration and try to figure out what plugin they are using. If that doesn't help you could just make a new question here describing what you want to do and asking for a plugin compatible with your wordpress version.